# Not able to retrieve $_POST values

Tags: php, post

I have order a plugin which works fine on my local computer and on the developers test server. But the plugin is not working on my prod. server.

After registretion, I should get `$_GET = add_success`. But I'm getting `edit_success`.
In the code, they are cheking different $_POST values, one of them being 'mode'.

Trying to output $_POST["mode"], gives me an empty result, even though I can see the data using Firebug:

```
default_role         subscriber
license_agreement_page  on
mode           addRec
terms             on
user_email     spstieng2@hotmail.com
user_fname     sdf
user_lname     sdf
username       ssdfsdf
web_address
```

Trying a simple `echo $_POST["mode"]`, I get nothing.
Also tried `print_r($_POST)`, and that only gives me `Array ( ) 1`.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to output?

Comment: what do you mean by output? What is the code you are trying to run?

Comment: please provide more info. Also, do print_r($_POST) what is the result of that?

Comment: You're going to have to show some code here.

Comment: Can you show the full code? And can you confirm that, as Marius asks below, you have no redirects built in? None using mod_rewrite and 301 either?

Comment: I do get a `302 Moved Temporarily`. Not sure what that is.

Comment: Yes, the plugin IS using 'header("location")' as Marius suggests.

Comment: What is the plugin?  Are you submitting a form, and are you sure the method is set to POST?

Comment: After 3-4 hours of debugging, I discovered that the plugin doesn't run a SQL query which should return a ID. Basically, the plugin is broken after it went through an update / cleanup. But you guys did help me troublewshoot the plugin. So thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but if you're getting results in $_GET, you shouldn't be getting them in $_POST.  Make sure the HTML form on the production server has method="post" instead of method="get".

Comment: It's not THE correct answer, but one of many helping hands which helped me trouble shoot and discover the error in the plugin. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it just "mode" or every variable? Have you tried printing the POST array?

Answer (score 1):

Do you redirect the browser in any way, using header("location"); or rewriterules?

If you use header("location: otherpage.php"); then `otherpage.php` will not receive the post data. You need to look into [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to pass [post data to a url](http://blog.mypapit.net/2006/02/sending-http-post-with-php-curl.html).

Comment: Yes. The plug IS using header("location"). The plugin was working fine before I updated the code with new code. The pugin works both on my local computer and on the developers test server.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the array content's with:

```
print_r($_POST);
```